# Is there any worthwhile optimization made by declaring local values with &&

Tags: c++11, scope, rvalue-reference, rvalue

In the following member function, is there any benefit at all to declare values `cc`, `dd`, `ee` and `ff` with `&&`?

```
void doStuff(double& aa, const size_t& bb) const {
    const double&& cc = 2*bb;
    const double&& dd = 2*sumT_;
    const double&& ee = sumTsq_ - scaledTSq_;
    const double&& ff = dd*dd - 2*cc*ee;
    aa = (ff >= 0) ? (dd + sqrt(ff))/cc : std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
}
```

Why not just plain `const double`?

Comment: Consider calculating the first "constant" as `double cc = 2.0 * bb;` to avoid a possible overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. There is no cost difference between move and copy for double.